# Чи правильніше вживати "ітевець" замість "айтівець"?

Tags: англіцизми

Як краще називати людей, що працюють у сфері інформаційних технологій?
"айтівець" починається з "айті", що є англійським скороченням від information technology, але якщо ми говоримо це саме українською, то замість "ай" та "ті" маємо "і" та "те", бо "інформаційні технології".

То чи правильніше буде казати "ітевець" ?

Comment: "Вам шашечки чи їхати"? Тобто, вам щоб розуміли чи щоб відповідно до [поки що неіснуючої] норми неологізму?